# Is there a good regular expression for multiline matching of received SIP invites?

Tags: python, regex

I really need python regexp which would give me this information:

Data:

> Received from 1.1.1.1 18:41:51:330
>   (123 bytes):
>
> INVITE: sip:dsafsdf@fsdafas.com To:
>   sdfasdfasdfas
>  From: "test"
>   
>  Via:
>   sdafsdfasdfasd
>
> Sent from 1.1.1.1 18:42:51:330
>   (123 bytes):
>
> INVITE: sip:dsafsdf@fsdafas.com
>   From: "test"
>   
>  To:
>   sdfasdfasdfas
>  Via:
>   sdafsdfasdfasd
>
> Received from 1.1.1.1 18:50:51:330
>   (123 bytes):
>
> INVITE: sip:dsafsdf@fsdafas.com
>   Via: sdafsdfasdfasd
>   From: "test"
>   
>  To:
>   sdfasdfasdfas

What I need to achieve, is to find the newest INVITE that was "Received" in order to get From: header value. So searching the data backwards.

Is it possible with unique regexp ? :)

Thanks.

Comment: I think that a multi-line regexp is the wrong approach to this problem. It can be done that way, but I think doing it the way I give in my answer has many advantages and is a better approach to solving the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

One-line answer, assuming you suck the entire header into a string with embedded newlines (or cr/nl's):

```
sorted(re.findall("Received [^\r\n]+ (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})[^\"]+From: \"([^\r\n]+)\"", data))[-1][1]
```

The trick to doing it with one RE is using [^\r\n] instead of . when you want to scan over stuff.  This works assuming from string always has the double quotes.  The double quotes are used to keep the scanner from swallowing the entire string at the first Received... ;)

Comment: I'd not solve this problem with regex but it is the question - and your answer is excellent. I'd suggest two things: to add white spaces in the `From` group (`From: \"([^\r\n\s]+)\"` for avoiding stuff like `To: sdfasdfasdfas` of the first match. Also, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://awurl.com/cnqClxt9m) such as `(?!.*Received [^\r\n]*\n.*INVITE)` at the end of regex so the search will return only the last occurrence. But these are only some details, your answer seems exactly what Mejmo was looking for.

Comment: +1: I think this is the wrong way to do it, and I think it's better to give the right way to do it. But this does answer the exact question the OP posed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a single regular expression is the answer. I think a stateful line-by-line matcher is what you're looking for here.

```
import re
import collections

_msg_start_re = re.compile('^(Received|Sent)\s+from\s+(\S.*):\s*$')
_msg_field_re = re.compile('^([A-Za-z](?:(?:\w|-)+)):\s+(\S(?:.*\S)?)\s*$')
def message_parser():
    hdr = None
    fields = collections.defaultdict(list)
    msg = None
    while True:
        if msg is not None:
            line = (yield msg)
            msg = None
            hdr = None
            fields = collections.defaultdict(list)
        else:
            line = (yield None)
        if hdr is None:
            hdr_match = _msg_start_re.match(line)
            hdr = None if hdr_match is None else hdr_match.groups()
        elif len(fields) <= 0:
            field_match = _msg_field_re.match(line)
            if field_match is not None:
                fields[field_match.group(1)].append(field_match.group(2))
        else: # Waiting for the end of the message
            if line.strip() == '':
                msg = (hdr, dict(fields))
            else:
                field_match = _msg_field_re.match(line)
                fields[field_match.group(1)].append(field_match.group(2))
```

Example of use:

```
parser = msg_parser()
parser.next()
recvd_invites = [msg for msg in (parser.send(line) for line in linelst) \
                   if (msg is not None) and \
                      (msg[0][0] == 'Received') and \
                      ('INVITE' in msg[1])]
```

You might be able to do this with a multiple line regex, but if you do it this way you get the message nicely parsed into its various fields. Presumably you want to do something interesting with the messages, and this will let you do a whole bunch more with them without having to use more regexps.

This also allows you to parse something other than an already existing file or a giant string with all the messages in it. For example, if you want to parse the output of a pipe that's printing out these requests as they happen you can simply do `msg = parser.send(line)` every time you receive a line and get a new message out as soon as its all been printed (if the line isn't the end of a message then `msg` will be `None`).